# How to get only the relevant index values from a filtered DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` like this:

```
t = [v for v in zip(['Tan'] * 5 + ['Rad'] * 5, ['min', 'max', 'var', 'rf', 'uf'] * 2)]
df = pd.DataFrame([1.,2,3,4,5]*2, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(t), columns=['val'])
```

That is

```
         val
Tan min  1.0
    max  2.0
    var  3.0
    rf   4.0
    uf   5.0
Rad min  1.0
    max  2.0
    var  3.0
    rf   4.0
    uf   5.0
```

As I filter this object with `df[df.val >= 3]` get

```
         val
Tan var  3.0
    rf   4.0
    uf   5.0
Rad var  3.0
    rf   4.0
    uf   5.0
```

However, if I want to get all the unique values from the index level 1 like this:

```
df[df.val >= 3].index.levels[1].unique()
```

The result will be

```
['max', 'min', 'rf', 'uf', 'var']
```

instead of just `['rf', 'uf', 'var']` which is what I expected to see.

How is it possible to fetch only the relevant values according to the filtered `DataFrame` I get with `df[df.val >= 3]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [*`get_level_values`*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
df[df.val >= 3].index.get_level_values(1).unique()
Index(['var', 'rf', 'uf'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of that method. Same for `remove_unused_levels()` to be honest. :)

Comment: @displayname Yes. The pandas API is vast. OTOH, this is a one step operation and you don't need to mutate the index.

Answer (score 3):

You need [`remove_unused_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html), `new in version 0.20.0.`:

```
df1 = df[df.val >= 3]

print (df1.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[['Rad', 'Tan'], ['max', 'min', 'rf', 'uf', 'var']],
           labels=[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3]])

df1.index = df1.index.remove_unused_levels()
print (df1.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[['Rad', 'Tan'], ['var', 'rf', 'uf']],
           labels=[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])


print (df1.index.levels[1])
Index(['var', 'rf', 'uf'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of this method, I should read the what's new sections more often +1

Comment: For both of you +1 , now I have 5 minutes left to decide which answer I like the most.

Comment: @displayname Note that with this answer you don't have to mutate the index. `df[df.val >= 3].index.remove_unused_levels().levels[1]` is enough.

Comment: Hmmm, I think it is not same methods. Because `.get_level_values` get desired output, but not remove unused levels.

Comment: Well in this particular case I was only interested in retrieving the relevant index values and not really in removing them, but I'm glad that I now know both methods :)